# Replace spaces with underscores when uploading file

Tags: javascript, replace, upload, spaces

I have a interface written for me that I am modifying a bit. I have this function to upload a file:

```
function importImage() {

    var imageName = $("#image").val();
    var tokens = imageName.split("\\");
    var imageName = tokens[tokens.length-1];

    if (imageName.length==0) {
        alert("Image File Required");
        return;
    }

    if ($("#userName").val().length==0) {
        $("#userName").val(imageName);
    }

    popupShow("Uploading, please wait");

    $('#imageImportForm').ajaxSubmit({ 
        "error": function(){
            alert("Unable to upload Image");
        },
        "dataType": "json",
        "success": function(response, statusText, xhr) {

            if (response["status"]!=1) {
                popupRemove();
                alert(response["message"]);
            } else {
                popupRemove();
                getImages();
                dataModel.addImage(0);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What I have found is in other parts of my interface it can be broken if the image being used has spaces in it. So to fix this I want to eliminate spaces from the files when they are uploaded. Curious how I could accomplish that by adding to this java string :).

Something like this maybe in the beginning:

```
var str = "#image";
var res = str.replace(/ /g,"_");
```

Comment: Are you talking about filename?

Comment: Fix your space issue on rendering - space (%20) is a valid character for a filename in common cases. Regardless, modifying the filename is within the server-side application, not your client-side javascript.

Comment: why not just encodeing it? encodeURIComponent("my image.jpg"); ?

Comment: I guess the difficult part for me is I don't really understand code well. So I was looking maybe something I could just inject into this already. not quite sure how the encode line is used...sorry very green over here guys. Ya I am looking to remove spaces from the file name and replace with a underscore or dash.

Comment: `var res = str.replace(/ /g,"_");` should work just fine... what's the question exactly?

Comment: Where would that be placed. Do I need to create a full function argument for only it?